# Where are ODBC drivers for MFC

Tags: database, mfc, odbc

I'm trying to create MFC application with DB support and during the project setup process I'm being asked to point out to location of ODBC drivers which are apparently provided with VS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f67e3x4.aspx
For the life of me I cannot find them.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, ODBC drivers ship with Windows. They are located at

> %WINDIR%\System32

and

> %WINDIR%\SysWOW64
>   (for 32-bit applications running on 64-bit Windows)